# locationServicesEnabled always return YES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I tested my device (iPod Touch 2G iOS 4.1) if location services are enabled

```
permitted = [locationManager locationServicesEnabled];
```

and I always get a YES whether location services are enabled or not. I'm talking about the general button for location services and not the app specific button. On iPad with iOS 3.2.2 everything is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you implement the delegate for location manager, you should be implementing didFailWithError. In there you will get the appropriate error if the user did not allow access to location

**[Apple Documentation States:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html)**
If the user denies your application’s use of the location service, this method reports a `kCLErrorDenied` error. Upon receiving such an error, you should stop the location service.

Comment: I did this but I'm talking about the general button for enabling/disabling location services (and not the extra button for each app). In addition `locationServicesEnabled` should not return YES if it is disabled.

Comment: many people get confused by this, but read the documentation link I provided, it will return yes.. you have to check for the error.

Comment: The only sentence I can find about that is in your answer. When does `locationServicesEnabled` returns NO? It does on the iPad ... The point why I am confused are `A Boolean value indicating whether location services are enabled on the device.` and `The user can enable or disable location services from the Settings application by toggling the Location Services switch in General.` So there is no difference for the general switch and the app specific switch.

Comment: And the funniest thing `You should check this property before starting location updates to determine whether the user has location services enabled for the current device. If this property contains the value NO and you start location updates anyway, the Core Location framework prompts the user with a confirmation alert asking whether location services should be reenabled.` Why checking if it always returns YES and if I don't check the iOS makes it for me ...

Answer (score 35):

Remember that `[locationManager locationServicesEnabled]` is [deprecated since iOS 4.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-AppendixA-DontLinkElementID_40).
Use the Class Method `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` instead.

[The App Specific Button can be retrieved by](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW11)

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]
```

Answer (score 8):

When you use

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]
```

then you inspect if locationServices are enabled in whole system. So when you go to Settings -> Location Services and you see that first switch. That method returns state of that state and is not in relation with your app.

If you need to know if your app has access to location services use @Pascalius answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift** 3.1 function returns -> status:Bool and message:String

```
func isLocationEnabled() -> (status: Bool, message: String) {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
        case .restricted, .denied:
            return (false,"No access")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            return(true,"Access")
        }
    } else {
        return(false,"Turn On Location Services to Allow App to Determine Your Location")
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing `.notDetermined` and adding it to the second `case` worked great for me.

Comment: @WaylanSands Thank you, I updated my answer based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

```
if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] || ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]!=kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse && [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]!=kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways))
{
        ; // app doesn't have access to localization to whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] will return NO when the user setting button is switched to OFF, only then I have achieved a NO.