# CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled always return TRUE in iOS 9

Tags: xcode, cllocationmanager, ios9.1

I've been doing some research about CoreLocation. Recently, I encountered a problem that is [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] is always return true in iOS 9.let me know why this happened..

Thanks

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034095/locationservicesenabled-always-return-yes or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969368/why-cllocationmanager-always-returns-true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that [locationManager locationServicesEnabled] is deprecated since iOS 4.0. Use the Class Method [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] instead.

***The App Specific Button can be retrieved by***

[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]